# How to ensure data is loaded before tableviewcontroller tries to load it

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

I have a UITableViewController and the problem I'm getting is NoMethodError 'length' for nil class - as @data is [] which otherwise returns rows when called in a different context , how can I ensure the data is loaded from the remote service before tableview attempts to load it?

```
    def viewDidLoad
        super
        loaddata
    end

    def loaddata
        @data = ().to_a
        AFMotion::Client.shared.get("api/v1/user") do |response|
        if response.success?
        d = response.object["user"]
          d.each {
           |item|
            aitem = item.new(item)
            @data << aitem
          }
       end
     end
    end

     def tableView(table_view, numberOfRowsInSection: section)                                           
         @data.length          //error here                                                                            
     end
```

Comment: is AFMotion::client some sort of async method which supports a call back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be (quick solution)

```
def tableView(table_view, numberOfRowsInSection: section)                                           
  loaddata unless @data
  @data.length          //error here                                                                            
end
```

Or (more ruby-like solution, but more refactoring required):

Change your loaddata method to:

```
def loaddata
  result = [] 
  AFMotion::client.shared.get("api/v1/user") do |response|
    if response.success?
      result = response.object["user"].map { |item| item.new(item) }
    end
  end
  result
end
```

Define new method:

```
def data
  @data ||= loaddata
end
```

Now use `data` instead of `@data`. It will ensure `loaddata` is called every time `data` is called for the first time and it will cache the results of that call.

Few more points:

1. naming convention - in ruby we use snakecase for methods and variable, so `table_view` instead of `tableView`
2. `AFMotion::client` - it is really hard to parse for me. Is `client` a module method (then should be rather `AFMotion.client`) or is it a module/class (should be then `AFMotion::Client`)

Comment: thanks you're suggestions got me there. You're right its AFMotion::Client, I'll update